# Appointment calendar php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to make an appointment system by php & mysql only. NO JS...
In this case, I have one table "requests" where I store data.

```css
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px 20px
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto 50px
}

th {
    height: 50px; text-transform: uppercase; font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>request_id</th>
<th>datetime</th>
<th>service_name</th>
<th>client</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2018-01-22 10:00:AM</td>
<td>Service 1</td>
<td>John Doe</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2</td>
<td>2018-01-22 02:00:PM</td>
<td>Service 1</td>
<td>Alex Star</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3</td>
<td>2018-01-22 03:00:PM</td>
<td>Service 2</td>
<td>Jane Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>

<form method="post" action="google.com">
    Service: <select>
  <?php $sql = 'select c.name service from services c order by c.name';
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo '<option>' . $row["service"] . "</option>"  ;
    }
}
        ?>
</select>
Date: <input id="datetime-local" name="date" type="datetime-local">
</form>
```

My question is: How can I restrict the input field datetime and show just available time.
Do you have any other ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I use this form on AMP page so it doesnt allow me any script

Comment: What does this have to do with mysql?

Comment: what are you defining the available time ? are you storing booked time any where ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MySQL [DATE_FORMAT(date,format)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) when doing the select query to return results.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime_field, '%T') as date_formatted FROM table_name
```

Definition of %T : Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)

EDIT:

Q: How can I restrict the input field datetime and show just available time.

A: If you are able to use HTML 5 it has the time input type which will make it so that you get a time selection dropdown from the input.

Comment: Yes. You're right. This is how I select date from my table. But how I can restrict my input type="datetime-local" not to show theese 2 dates ?

Comment: @IustinBeceneagă Add this extra code to your question/example please. If you want to alter the user input value as it is input, you're going to need to use JS. You could however alter it after the form has been posted with PHP? Theres also HTML5's time input type: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time

Comment: Is there any other option that not involves JS ?

Comment: @IustinBeceneagă Updated my answer with what I think is correct but please let me know if you're still battling with this as i might have misunderstood your question.

Comment: I am able to use HTML5. That table stores my clients appointments. So when I use the form  to do another appointment, I want that 3 dates from my table been disabled in the form...before submiting it

Comment: @IustinBeceneagă Okay I think I understand, you want to have certain dates disabled in your form, so if you've already got an appointment for 2pm today, the form must have 2pm greyed out for today?